# The website restriction for the Google API key is not working

Tags: google-api

I generated a Google API key, and I need to restrict it only to websites whose domain is 'hangry.sg.' I have tried various ways, but it is not working. I have attached a photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKMUK.png)

I tried,but they did not work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "did not work"?  That is not much of a problem description. 
 Please tell us what you **actually tried**, and tell us what the **actual results** were, and explain how those results weren't what you **expected**.

Comment: Could you please look at the image "enter image description here".